# Complex geometry - Cohomology groups of line bundles on the projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I want to show that $$H^{1}(P^1 , O_{P^1} (−1)) = 0$$ and that $ H^{1}(P^1 , O_{P^1} (-2))$ does not vanish, via Cech Cohomology (another possibility for the first result would be Riemann-Roch theorem), using the standard open sets $U_0$ and $U_1$ on $P_1$.
I assume it is quite a basic problem, and I have already seen exercices on Cech cohomology but it was always with locally constant sheaves. I feel a bit confused trying to compute cohomology groups for the sheaf $O_{P^1} (−1)$.
Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: look at where it's been done before. This computation is very well covered in the literature: for instance, [here's the Stacks Project proof using Cech cohomology](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XS), [section 19.3 in Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGaug2922public.pdf) gives a bit of a guided tour while still making you do some of the work, Hartshorne chapter III section 5 contains the full computation, etc.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you very much. I’ve already come across this proof but at first sight it was too hard for me, knowing that I come from the differential geometry world and thus complex geometry results using algebraic geometry concepts are tough to clearly understand. I will try !

Comment: If you have specific questions, you can [edit] them in to your post. This site works much better when you can point to specific things you're having trouble with - it also works better when you can explain some of your background (what you've seen before that's relevant to the problem, what you know that's relevant to the problem, etc). For more tips, see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on meta.

Comment: So edit your post to include the details of the set-up for Cech cohomology. You have an obvious open covering, so what are sections of $\mathscr O(k)$ on $U_i$?

Comment: @TedShrifin For $O(-1)$, the sections should be the maps that take an $l \in U_i$ and give $(l,z)$ with some $z \in l$ . I have trouble to see clearly how those are considered in practice, in order to show that the first cohomology group actually vanishes. 
In the Cech complex, $Ker(\delta_1) = C^1(U,O_{P^1}(-1))$  (because $C^2(U,O_{P^1}(-1) = 0$, there are just two open sets), so I want to show that $\delta_0$ is actually surjective, but I don’t get it.

Comment: You want to be thinking about homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$ and transition functions.